# T-SQL Query Column based on filtered condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I could do this rather easily in Python (or any other language), but I'm trying to see if this is possible with pure T-sql

I have two tables:

Table A has a bunch of general data and timestamps with each row

```
+------+------+------+-----------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Timestamp |
+------+------+------+-----------+
| A    | B    | C    | 17:00     |
| D    | E    | F    | 18:00     |
| G    | H    | I    | 23:00     |
+------+------+------+-----------+
```

Table B is considered metadata

```
+-------+-----------+
| RunNo | Timestamp |
+-------+-----------+
|     1 | 16:50     |
|     2 | 17:30     |
|     3 | 18:00     |
|     4 | 19:00     |
+-------+-----------+
```

So the general data is referenced to a "RunNo". The timestamp in table B is just when that "Run" was created in the DB. You can match the General data to its proper run number by comparing the timestamps. For example the timestamp for the first row in Table A is 17:00 which is greater than 16:50 and less than 17:30, so obviously this row belongs to RunNo 1. How can I perform this query so the resulting table is

```
+------+------+------+-----------+-------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Timestamp | RunNo |
+------+------+------+-----------+-------+
| A    | B    | C    | 17:00     |     1 |
| D    | E    | F    | 18:00     |     2 |
| G    | H    | I    | 23:00     |     4 |
+------+------+------+-----------+-------+
```

I though maybe using CASE would be helpful here, but I couldn't figure how to put it togther

```
SELECT a.*,
       CASE WHEN a.TIMESTAMP < b.TIMESAMP AND a.TIMESTAMP > b.TIMSTAMP then b.RunNo END AS RunNo
FROM A as a, B as b
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `For example the timestamp for the first row in Table A is 17:00 which is greater than 16:50 and less than 17:30, so obviously this row belongs to RunNo 1` This is likely not going to be obvious to anyone except you or someone who is familiar with your process. Consider making your relationships more explicit by assigning unique identifiers to each run so that nobody needs to infer relationships using timestamps.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? Newer versions offer some more efficient approaches.

Comment: Why is the second column with D, E, F not in run 3? Run 3 starts at 18:00.

Comment: I didn't create this DB nor do I have the ability to update it. I'm an end user trying to scrape data. There are a lot of erroneous values in other tables that would make this join easier, therefore, i'm relegated to utilizing the timestamps since there are no issues with those. I'm using sql server 2017

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes because due to the nature of what the data actually is, if there is an observation that shares the "same" timestamp (I put same in "" since seconds and milliseconds aren't shown) with a newly created run, that data was created by the previous run. i.e. there is a delay between when a run is created and when it can actually start recording data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CASE` allows you to return different values (i.e. columns or expressions) based on a condition. This is not what you what here. You want to join tables and filter matching rows based on a condition.

I have replaced the name `Timestamp` with `ts`, as even escaped, I had difficulties with it on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com). It is a reserved keyword.

```
SELECT A.Col1, A.Col2, A.Col3, A.ts, MAX(B.RunNo) AS RunNo
FROM
    A
    INNER JOIN B
        ON A.ts > B.ts
GROUP BY A.Col1, A.Col2, A.Col3, A.ts
```

With `A.ts > B.ts` this returns `RunNo` 2 for the second entry. With `A.ts >= B.ts` this returns `RunNo` 3 for the second entry.

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9dd143/6/0

Answer (score 0):

```
with TableA as (
    Select [Col1] = 'A',[Col2] = 'B',[Col3] = 'C',[Timestamp] = '17:00'
    Union all Select [Col1] = 'D',[Col2] = 'E',[Col3] = 'F',[Timestamp] = '18:00'
    Union all Select [Col1] = 'G',[Col2] = 'H',[Col3] = 'I',[Timestamp] = '23:00'
)
, TableB as (
    Select [RunNo] = '1',[Timestamp] = '16:50'
    Union all Select [RunNo] = '2',[Timestamp] = '17:30'
    Union all Select [RunNo] = '3',[Timestamp] = '18:00'
    Union all Select [RunNo] = '4',[Timestamp] = '19:00'
)
, TableBWithRowNumber as (
    select b.RunNo, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by b.timestamp asc) as number, cast(b.Timestamp as time) as timestamp
    from TableB b
)
, TableBWithNextRun as (
    select b1.RunNo, startTime = b1.timestamp , endTime = b2.timestamp
    from TableBWithRowNumber b1
    left join TableBWithRowNumber b2 on b1.number + 1= b2.number
)
select * 
from TableA a
inner join TableBWithNextRun B 
    on a.Timestamp >= b.startTime and (a.Timestamp < b.endTime or b.endTime is null)
```

This converts your timestamps to `time`. I wasn't sure what you're datatype is internally.

This outputs the following

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Timestamp   RunNo   startTime           endTime
A       B       C       17:00       1       16:50:00.0000000    17:30:00.0000000
D       E       F       18:00       3       18:00:00.0000000    19:00:00.0000000
G       H       I       23:00       4       19:00:00.0000000    NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lag function to get the prior value of a column and then just join.

```
WITH Runs AS
(
  SELECT
    RunNo, 
    COALESCE(LAG(TIMESTAMP),'00:00')) AS START_TS,
    TIMESTAMP AS END_TS
  FROM TableB
  ORDER BY RunNo ASC
)
SELECT B.RunNo, A.*
FROM TableA A
JOIN Runs B ON A.Timestamp >= B.Start_TS AND A.Timestamp < B.End_Ts
```

This should be faster than any group by solution on larger datasets.